# How to work with Code injection model in Visual studio C++ Managed unit test Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

this is my Employee.h file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<iomanip>
#define SIZEOF(array)   (int)sizeof(array)
#define sort  stable_sort
using namespace std;

struct employee_rec
{
char name[30];
char department[15];
double salary;
};

 class VEMPLOYEE : public vector<employee_rec>
{
public:
VEMPLOYEE();
~VEMPLOYEE();

void InitEmployee(employee_rec& emp);
    //This method loads the person details from input.txt file
void LoadAndProcessDetails(employee_rec& emp, char* Inputfile, double value);

//This method increments the particular percentage of a salary
void IncrementSalary(employee_rec& emp, double value);

//This method writes the Results to output file
void WriteDetails(employee_rec& emp, char* Outputfile);

void PrintToOutFile(ofstream& outfile, const employee_rec* w);

ifstream& ReadFile(ifstream& infile, employee_rec& emp);    
static inline bool Cmpemp(const employee_rec& x, const employee_rec& y);
```

};

And my Main Employee.cpp

```
#include"EmployeeManagement.h"

VEMPLOYEE::VEMPLOYEE()
{

}
VEMPLOYEE::~VEMPLOYEE()
{

}

VEMPLOYEE Actualemployee;
employee_rec emp;
VEMPLOYEE MyTestvector;
void VEMPLOYEE::InitEmployee(employee_rec& emp)
{   
strcpy_s(emp.department, " ");
strcpy_s(emp.name, " ");
emp.salary = 0.0;
}
ifstream& VEMPLOYEE::ReadFile(ifstream& infile, employee_rec& emp)
{
infile >> emp.name >> emp.department >> emp.salary;
return infile;
}

void VEMPLOYEE::LoadAndProcessDetails(employee_rec& emp, char* Inputfile, double value)
{
int i = 0;
int ops = 0;
ifstream infile;
InitEmployee(emp);
infile.open(Inputfile, ios::in);
while (ReadFile(infile, emp))
{  
    ++ops;
    IncrementSalary(emp, value);
    Actualemployee.push_back(emp);
}
std::sort(Actualemployee.begin(), Actualemployee.end(), Cmpemp);
infile.close();
}

bool VEMPLOYEE::Cmpemp(const employee_rec& x, const employee_rec& y)
{
int n;
n = strcmp(x.department, y.department);
if (n<0) return 1;
if (n == 0)
{
    n = strcmp(x.name, y.name);
    if (n<0) return 1;
    if (n == 0 && x.salary < y.salary) return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void VEMPLOYEE::IncrementSalary(employee_rec& emp, double value)
{
emp.salary += ((emp.salary / 100) * value);
}

void VEMPLOYEE::WriteDetails(employee_rec& emp, char* Outputfile)
{
vector<employee_rec>::iterator iter1;
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(Outputfile, ios::out);
for (iter1 = Actualemployee.begin(); iter1 != Actualemployee.end(); ++iter1)
{

    PrintToOutFile(outfile, &*iter1);
}
        outfile.close();
}

void VEMPLOYEE::PrintToOutFile(ofstream& outfile, const employee_rec* w)
{
outfile << setw(15) << left << w->name << setw(7) << w->department << setw(7) << w->salary << "\n";
}

int main()
{
VEMPLOYEE inc;
double value;
employee_rec emp1;
cout << "Enter which percent to increment \n";
cin >> value;
inc.LoadAndProcessDetails(emp, "Input.txt", value);
inc.WriteDetails(emp, "Output.txt");
return 0;
}
```

Input.txt file

```
Dany IT 10000
Loky IT 15000
Rony IT 25000
```

From Visualstudio2015 C++ Managed Test Project
Employee_Test.cpp file is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;
std::ofstream LogFile;

namespace EmployeeManagementSystem_MDM_Test
{
[TestClass]
public ref class EmployeeManagement_Testing 
{
private:
    TestContext^ testContextInstance;

public: 
    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    property Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ TestContext
    {
        Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ get()
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        System::Void set(Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ value)
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    };

        [TestInitialize]
        void TestInitialize()
        {
            char* testName = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(TestContext->TestName).ToPointer();
            LogFile << "Test Case " << testName << " Started Executing" << std::endl;
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)testName);
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        void TestCleanup()
        {
            char* testName = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(TestContext->TestName).ToPointer();
            LogFile << "Test Case " << testName << " Completed Executing" << std::endl;
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)testName);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        void LoadAndProcessDetails_Test()
        {
            ifstream infile;
            int i = 0;
            size_t n = 9;
            VEMPLOYEE Expectedemployee;
            employee_rec    emp_Test;
            infile.open("Output_Expected.txt",ios::in);
            if (!infile)
            exit(1);

            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                infile >> emp_Test.name >>  emp_Test.department >> emp_Test.salary;

                Expectedemployee.push_back(emp_Test);
            }

            infile.close();             

            VEMPLOYEE inc1;
            employee_rec emp1;
            inc1.LoadAndProcessDetails(emp1, "Input.txt", 10);
            ofstream outfile;
            Assert::AreEqual(Expectedemployee.size(), Actualemployee.size());
        };
    };
}
```

ExpectedOutput.txt is(10 % increment in salary)

```
    Dany IT 11000
    Loky IT 16500
    Rony IT 27500
```

My C++ Project Employee management system And it Reads the employee details from the text file(Input.txt) and increments the salary by n Percent, Results prints in the text file(Output.txt).

TestProject:-

In visual studio 2015 Manged C++ Test Project, And I created test method for my actual project, Testing the function in the actual project.

I am trying to do is

->Test the actual method and examining the functionality of employee project

My goals:-

1.I created ExpectdOutput.txt file and compare with Original output in the main 
  Project.

2.If there are any dissimilarities in ActualOutput.txt(From the main program) and ExpectedOutput.txt(From my Test Project) file, Those values dump into one text file.

And I am able to test only the sizes of my expectedOutpt(From text project) size and ActualOutput(From main Project).

But I want to compare all records(each) and individually and mismatched values Print into a text file??

To achieve goals which code I suppose to add in my test project (Employee_testing) [But I don't want to change any code in my actual Employee Project].
Please give me any suggestions ??